# Grant Permissions to List Items using existing SharePoint Group using Client Object Model

Tags: permissions, client-object-model, custom

I have found examples on how to add users to SharePoint Groups using Client Object Model.  Can anyone help provide an example on how to grant permissions to items in a List using an existing SharePoint group?  I dont need to create the group in code, nor add users to the group.  I also do not need to add roles to the SharePoint Group.  I simply need to grant permissions to the List Item using the existing SharePoint Group.

Thanks for any tips provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create RoleDefinitionBinding object set the type of permissions to it and add it as parameter to RoleAssignments of list item. There is example of how to add group with read permissions to list item:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
  class BreakSecurityInheritanceAddUser
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      string siteUrl = "Your site url";
      ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
      SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Your List Name");

      int itemId = 3;
      ListItem oListItem = oList.Items.GetById(itemId); //Get List Item by id

      oListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);



RoleDefinitionBindingCollection collRoleDefinitionBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext);

  collRoleDefinitionBinding.Add(clientContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Reader)); //Set permission type

  oListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(oGroup, collRoleDefinitionBinding); //oGroup - your SPGroup

  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  What would I pass in place of the "oGroup" parameter?  Let's say my SharePoint Group name is "TestGroup".  The group already has permissions assigned (for example, CONTRIBUTE).  Do I still need to set the permission type?

Comment: "oGroup" is an object type "Group": 
GroupCollection groups = web.SiteGroups;
clientContext.Load(groups, groupitems => groupitems.Include(groupitem => groupitem.Title,
groupitem => groupitem.Description).Where(groupitem=> groupitem.Title == "TestGroup"));
Permission is for list item. What did you mean by that group has contribute permission? Your group has permission for site? For list? For item?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad example.  "TestGroup" has READ permissions.  And it would be granting permissions to the list item, so granting "TestGroup" to the list item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

check this blog, he is using the visual studio via COM
http://model-view-controller.net/2012/09/20/set-permission-to-group-in-sharepoint-2010-programmatically-using-vs-2010-via-com/

also check this MSDN for complete How to
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537013(v=office.14).aspx