# How to change item Permission on Sharepoint Online Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I want to ask a question, how to change permission to the element by Sharepoint Online ? How could I identify user. Could I Identify user by email ? Or it should be done only by account ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the OOB powershell commands for SharePoint online don't include changing permissions, this is something that will have to be done via CSOM. You can code it yourself, see [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85703/grant-permissions-to-list-items-using-existing-sharepoint-group-using-client-obj) for an example, or you can use the SharePoint PnP project, and use the code that others have already written and tested. [This page](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/readme.md) lists all the available PowerShell commands that are in the PnP project. Just do a find on the page for the word "permission" to find the applicable cmdlets. [This](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) page has the installation instructions for getting started with it.